# Error when I search for some specific words in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-services, visual-web-part, sharepoint-search

I have a custom webpart on the search page which is getting data from an external web service.

I am getting the following error when I am searching for some specific words (e.g test) in sharePoint 2010.

[image]

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Without seeing the code it is hard to help you. But the error message point on an Access Denied error. Can it be that the search is done in an elevated context and then tries to displays items to you that you should not be able to see, and hence throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

Found out: The exception was thrown at another place in code and i didn't saw it.

[image]

A farm level feature responsible to write logging to event viewer was not activated.